# Numpy reshape "reversal"

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

I read a 4D array from a file which is given in a 2D form i, j, k, x, y, z. 
[Input file header and shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aft8s.png)
I use numpy.reshape to reshape the 2D array to it's 3-D form. After making changes to this, I wish to write the file exactly the same order / format as I read it. 
I do not understand how to "reverse" numpy.reshape to put it back in the same format.

```
import numpy as np    
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv 


header = read_csv("Input/Grid1_test.csv", nrows=1,skipinitialspace=True)

print header.head()

imax=header['IMAX'].iloc[0]
jmax=header['JMAX'].iloc[0]
kmax=header['KMAX '].iloc[0]

print(imax,jmax,kmax)

#read grid data with numpy array .. it is slow but probably worth it 
grid_data = np.loadtxt('Input/Grid1_test.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=3)


size_arr = np.array(grid_data).reshape(kmax, jmax, imax, 6)

#do something

#write the grid back into the file
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To "reverse" a reshape, you can just call `reshape` again on the array to reshape it into the original dimensions.

If you have an array `x` with dimensions (`n`, `m`) then:

```
x.reshape(kmax, jmax, imax, 6).reshape(n, m) == x
```

Comment: Thanks Henry, that works! I should have thought of it  :)